# User login validation by url

Tags: spring-security

I've a application with login form, this works well.

Now I've some provider that send  url as "http://server/springapplication/**country**?username=user&password=pass" to my spring program

How to implement authentification of this url  and redirect to controller **country**?

I work withy spring security anottations.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In these days I have been experimenting situations for this implementations. I have other case. Some customers send to my spring aplication some xml document in the post request. This document contains user and password in it, i need process this data to login my aplication. If I implement http.basic() and  my class extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, spring security doesn't authentificate the request. I had thinking implement the authentification request in controllers when custumer send xml document, but I think this isn't a good idea.

What do you think about this.?